# Xcode/React-native : Undefined symbol: _swift_getFunctionReplacement

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, mapbox, xcodebuild

I have a react-native project and I started getting following error in my xcode build after I installed some mapbox related pods.

```
ld: warning: building for iOS, but linking in dylib file (/Users/nitinsharma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-bpqejjqomhurrldtyubqevqtdqzc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MapboxAccounts.framework/MapboxAccounts) built for Mac Catalyst
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_swift_getFunctionReplacement", referenced from:
      _swift_getFunctionReplacement50 in libswiftCompatibilityDynamicReplacements.a(DynamicReplaceable.cpp.o)
     (maybe you meant: _swift_getFunctionReplacement50)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now the error goes aways if I follow these steps

```
 1. Go to project>build settings> library search path
 2. remove "$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"
```

However after that I am not able to install the app as I get following error when xcode tries to install the app on my device. I even tried deleting `DerivedData` folder but no luck

```
Details

Unable to install "app"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124ca7c8f DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124ce6241 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010950764b DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000124ce5f82 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000124b56a10 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3513
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010963617e __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000109637da0 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7182e6c4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7182f658 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff71834c44 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff718355d6 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7183ec09 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71a89a3d _pthread_wqthread + 290
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff71a88b77 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021)
Xcode 12.4 (17801) (Build 12D4e)
```

I am using `react native v0.63.0` and `Xcode 12.4` and my device is running `iOS 14.4`

```
Mapbox related pods that are installed

mapbox related pods from my podfile.lock
 - Mapbox-iOS-SDK (6.3.0):
    - MapboxMobileEvents (~> 0.10.4)
 - MapboxAccounts (2.3.1)
 - MapboxCommon (9.2.0)
 - MapboxCoreNavigation (1.2.1):
    - MapboxAccounts (~> 2.3.0)
    - MapboxDirections (~> 1.2.0)
    - MapboxMobileEvents (~> 0.10.2)
    - MapboxNavigationNative (~> 30.0)
    - Turf (~> 1.0)
 - MapboxDirections (1.2.0):
    - Polyline (~> 5.0)
    - Turf (~> 1.0)
 - MapboxMobileEvents (0.10.7)
 - MapboxNavigation (1.2.1):
    - Mapbox-iOS-SDK (~> 6.0)
    - MapboxCoreNavigation (= 1.2.1)
    - MapboxMobileEvents (~> 0.10.2)
    - MapboxSpeech (~> 1.0)
    - Solar (~> 2.1)
 - MapboxNavigationNative (30.0.0):
    - MapboxCommon (= 9.2.0)
 - MapboxSpeech (1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same errors in my project. Tried everything in here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/25

And what finally resolved it was to change `Don't Dead-strip Inits and Terms` to `Yes` for both Project and Target.

[image: Xcode project settings]

Comment: And keep you Library search path

Comment: Can you be more specific with this second recommendation?